# Complex navigation using NavigationComponent (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have 5 fragments (**StartFragment, UploadFragment, ListFragment, MoreFragment, SelectionFragment**) in a navigation graph. There are several scenarios where a user can navigate from **StartFragment** to **ListFragment** and **UploadFragment**.

**NavigationGraph:**
[image: NavigationGraph:]

**Scenario 1:**
*StartFragment->UploadFragment->ListFragment*

**Scenario 2:**
*StartFragment->ListFragment->UploadFragment->ListFragment*
**(Backpress from List fragment will navigate to StartFragment)**

**Scenario 3:**
*StartFragment->MoreFragment->ListFragment->UploadFragment->ListFragment*
**(Backpress from Listfragment will navigate to MoreFragment)**

**main_nav.xml:**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/startFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/startFragment"
        android:name="com.example.stackanswers.fragments.StartFragment"
        android:label="start_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/start_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_uploadFragment"
            app:destination="@id/uploadFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_listFragment"
            app:destination="@id/listFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_startFragment_to_moreFragment"
            app:destination="@id/moreFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/uploadFragment"
        android:name="com.example.stackanswers.fragments.UploadFragment"
        android:label="UploadFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_uploadFragment_to_listFragment"
            app:destination="@id/listFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:name="com.example.stackanswers.fragments.ListFragment"
        android:label="ListFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_selectionFragment"

            app:destination="@id/selectionFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_listFragment_to_uploadFragment"

            app:destination="@id/uploadFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/selectionFragment"
        android:name="com.example.stackanswers.fragments.SelectionFragment"
        android:label="SelectionFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_selectionFragment_to_listFragment"
            app:destination="@id/listFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/moreFragment"
        android:name="com.example.stackanswers.fragments.MoreFragment"
        android:label="MoreFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_moreFragment_to_listFragment"
            app:destination="@id/listFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**Problem with the current approach:**

- If I consider **scenario 1** then it is a straightforward solution. I have to remove UploadFragment from the backStack keeping StartFragment.
  `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.action_uploadFragment_to_listFragment)`
- But for **Scenerio 2 & 3**, if I use the above approach we will get 2
  ListFragment one top of another. I have to remove UploadFragment from the backStack keeping MoreFragment and StartFragment.

If I use `popBackstack()` then the first scene won't work. I can always use backStackCount and handle this the old way. But, this is just a simple scenario that I am trying to solve. There can be more complex scenarios the backStackCount count won't be a big help.

**Questions:**

- Is there a way to replace the already existing fragment with the instance or can we navigate to the already existing fragment without creating a duplicate(keeping the above scenario in mind)?
- Can I clear the current fragment from backstack only and then move to a new fragment? (For removing UploadFragment from backstack)
- The best practice for handling scenarios like this?